# What is sps.x inside the main liberry blocks of matlab simulink?

Tags: simulink

Inside the some of Simulink main blocks, a parameter is used like sps.k, sps.n ...
what is sps.? when should we use sps. with parameter name in mask blocks?
 for example inside the Fourier block in SimPowerSystems library you can see this.

Comment: It looks like `sps` is a `struct` with `x`, `n` and `k` being fields of the struct.  But it's hard to be certain as you haven't indicated a specific block to look at.

Comment: Dear Phil Goddard 
Thanks for your answer.
fourier block in  SimPowerSystems library for example.